# Getting pattern mismatch error while sharing a folder using Dropbox API

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am working on an Android app which uses Dropbox Core SDK v3.0.3.
While trying to share a folder with another member, I am constantly getting an error. The code is creating a new shared folder in the specified name, but not adding any members.

This is my code:

```
List<AddMember> list = new ArrayList<AddMember>();
AddMember newMember = new AddMember(MemberSelector.email(clerkDbId), AccessLevel.EDITOR);
list.add(newMember);
ShareFolderLaunch sfl = dbxClient.sharing().shareFolder("/" + clerkName);
dbxClient.sharing().addFolderMember(sfl.getCompleteValue().toString(), list); //I am getting error here.
```

**clerkName**: Name of the shared folder

**clerkDbId**: Dropbox id to which I want to share the above folder

I tried changing the first line to:

```
ArrayList<AddMember> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Still I am getting the same error. This is the error I am getting:

> String 'sharedFolderId' does not match pattern
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String 'sharedFolderId' does not
>   match pattern
>       at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.AddFolderMemberArg.(AddFolderMemberArg.java:50)
>       at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.AddFolderMemberArg.(AddFolderMemberArg.java:86)
>       at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.DbxUserSharingRequests.addFolderMember(DbxUserSharingRequests.java:154)
>       at com.dbapp.ashworth.adminapp.FilesActivity$3$1.doInBackground(FilesActivity.java:126)
>       at com.dbapp.ashworth.adminapp.FilesActivity$3$1.doInBackground(FilesActivity.java:115)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the `sharedFolderId` parameter value that you're passing to [`addFolderMember`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#addFolderMember-java.lang.String-java.util.List-) doesn't appear to be a valid shared folder ID.

You're passing in the entire [`SharedFolderMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/SharedFolderMetadata.html) (as a string). You should instead just get the shared folder ID like this:

`sfl.getCompleteValue().getSharedFolderId();`

By the way, when calling [`shareFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#shareFolder-java.lang.String-), you're not guaranteed to get the completed information immediately. You should use [`ShareFolderLaunch.isComplete`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/ShareFolderLaunch.html#isComplete--)/[`ShareFolderLaunch.isAsyncJobId`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/ShareFolderLaunch.html#isAsyncJobId--) to check what you got back. There's more information in the [`shareFolder documentation`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#shareFolder-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Is it possible to accept a 'share folder' invitation (Add to Dropbox) programmatically?

Comment: Yes, use [`mountFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#mountFolder-java.lang.String-) on the recipient's account.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. How to get the `sharedFolderId`? The `mountFolder` function requires `sharedFolderId` to mount a folder. Is it necessary to know the folder path?

Can you tell me what are the two parameters of `FolderMetadata.newBuilder(name, id)`?

Comment: You can get the `sharedFolderId` from the `SharedFolderMetadata` as above, or you can list all of the available shared folders for mounting in the recipient's connected account using [`listMountableFolders`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listMountableFolders--)/[`listMountableFoldersContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listMountableFoldersContinue-java.lang.String-).

Comment: You don't need to know the original folder path. You specify whatever path for where you want to mount the shared folder in the recipient's account. You also don't need to build `FolderMetadata` yourself, as you can just retrieve it from the various methods.

Comment: When I am using client.sharing().listFolders().getEntries(), it is returning even deleted folders which are not visible in my Dropbox account. What could be the reason? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to unmounted folders, per [`ListFoldersResult`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/ListFoldersResult.html): "Unmounted shared folders can be identified by the absence of `SharedFolderMetadata.getPathLower()`."